# Return view to original place after moving

Tags: android, coordinates, android-view, motionevent

I have a layout which contains `text` and wraps it. I need to move this `layout` vertically on the screen.

This is what I do.

```
View valuesContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.valuesContainer);
valuesContainer.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    oldY = (int)event.getRawY();
                    initialTopMargin = params.topMargin;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    newY = (int)event.getY();
                    params.topMargin = (int) (initialTopMargin - (oldY - newY));
                    v.setLayoutParams(params);
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

This moves the layout vertically on the screen. But now, I need this layout to go back to it's original place when I quit the finger of the screen.

Any code would be appriciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
     params.topMargin = initialTopMargin;
     v.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **ACTION_UP** to move the layout back to its original position. Below is the code. Try it.

```
View valuesContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.valuesContainer);

valuesContainer.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    oldY = (int)event.getRawY();
                    initialTopMargin = params.topMargin;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    newY = (int)event.getY();
                    params.topMargin = (int) (initialTopMargin - (oldY - newY));
                    v.setLayoutParams(params);
                    break;
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    params.topMargin = initialTopMargin;
                    v.setLayoutParams(params);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the initial pos when you get the `ACTION_DOWN` event. Handle the `ACTION_UP` event and, in there, set it to top again. If you want it to be smooth, launch a new thread updating the value and waiting or something.